# How to display a map on my wesbite and allow user to choose a country

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a known way where I can display a world map on my website and allow the user to choose a country to give him the appropriate content?

I know I can embed google maps, but for google maps, the user has unnecessary controls including zooming that I don't want to bother him with.

I would rather not use flash for this.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: This link may be useful for you http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/

Comment: Note that using map for selection is not always very practical: many countries are very, very small and can be quite difficult to select on a map showing the whole world.

Comment: Check out this example that shows how to disable the extra controls: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI , regarding choosing country you have multiple options, but one to consider is trying to choose based on where the user comes from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Comment: You can create a world map in SVG, and interact with it using javascript. http://www.270towin.com like they are using for the usa elections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jqvmap](https://jqvmap.com/) seems to be perfect for the needs stated exactly.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a select element with a list of countries. Each option should contain a two-letter ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code. When you select a country you can execute geocoding request for the country using components filtering. The response will return boundaries for the country, so you can fit Google maps to these boundaries.

Please find an example on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/qaxucex/edit?html,output

**code snippet:**

```js
  var map;
  var geocoder;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
      zoom: 1
    });
    
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    
    var countryControlDiv = document.getElementById('countries');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(countryControlDiv);
  }
  
  function showCountry(code) {
    if (code === "") {
       map.setOptions({
          center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
          zoom: 1
       });
    } else {
       geocoder.geocode({
          componentRestrictions: {
            country: code
          }
       }, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' +
            status);
          }
        });
    }
  }
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  #countries {
    margin-top: 12px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="countries">
  <select id="country" onchange="showCountry(this.value);">
    <option value="">--Select country--</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
    <option value="ES">Spain</option>
    <option value="US">USA</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&v=3&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: As far as I understand it, OP wants the user to select the country using a map rather than a list / drop down.